# Github pages duplicating header from jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am creating a website with Jekyll that when rendered locally works well, but when deployed on github replaces the website title with my first markdown header from my index.md file.

This just started happening today, it was rendering just fine up to yesterday.

Any ideas?

Comment: GitHub just [announced](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3) at update to GitHub Pages which changes the defaults for a bunch of stuff. Not sure, but it may be related.

Comment: thanks! it was a combination of the following two issues:
"If your page doesn't have an explicit title, and the file begins with an H1, H2, or H3, we'll use that heading as the page's title, which appears in places like browser tabs." and "If you don't specify a page's layout or title, and expect either to be unset (e.g., if you need to serve unstyled content), you'll need to explicitly set those values as null."